# Understanding of real field $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin. Theorem 1.19 in the book says that

> "there exists an ordered field $\Bbb{R}$ which has the least-upper-bound property".

Then author have called members of $\Bbb{R}$ as real numbers. As the proof was bit long, author gave it at the end of chapter. I too skip the proof for some time and went on reading further theorems assuming $\Bbb{R}$ to be our real line but now when I look the proof, real field $\Bbb{R}$ constructed by author is completely different. The members of $\Bbb{R}$ are some subsets of $\Bbb{Q}$ (he called them cuts). I got what author did and his construction but now when I look again at the theorems 1.20 and 1.21 with author's newly constructed field $\Bbb{R}$ ( which I was assuming our real line), they are not making much sense to me.

I am somehow confused all of a sudden  what exactly going on. Can someone please help to explain  author's constructed real field $\Bbb{R}$ (whose members are cuts). Is this same as our normal real field (whose members are numbers)?

Comment: You believe in the real "numbers", somehow. Have you ever constructed them? That's what Rudin shows you how to do, from basic principles.

Comment: All ordered fields with the lub property are isomorphic (as ordered fields) so if you have "numbers" in mind with those properties then the cuts construction (or Cauchy sequences or whatever other construction you prefer) is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388454/ontological-and-notational-question-concerning-vectors-and-matrices/3389479#3389479

Comment: Does it make sense to you that Rudin says the set $\mathbb{Q}^*$ of rational cuts  is the "same" as $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Jack ...yes.. familiar with concept of isomorphism

Comment: @Believer: so it is not very surprising that $\mathbb{R}$ by the construction of "cuts" is the same as "our normal real field" (whatever that means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone please help to explain author's constructed real field R( whose members are cuts). Is this same as our normal real field(whose members are numbers)?

Yes, it is the same. Cuts **are** numbers.

There are many different ways to construct the real numbers from the rational numbers (two popular constructions in particular, but I'm sure there are more exotic ones out there). Using so-called Dedekind cuts is one. Regardless of the construction chosen, the elements of the construction will not "look like" numbers (whatever that means). But they are numbers nonetheless.

A cut is a non-empty, upwards-bounded subset $X$ of the rational numbers with no maximal element, where each element of $X$ is a lower bound for the complement of $X$. (Some define a cut to be the pair consisting of $X$ and the complement of $X$.) This is *defined* to be the real number that intuitively corresponds to the least upper bound of $X$. So the cut construction of the real numbers intuitively takes $\Bbb Q$, and "injects" least upper bounds to all sets that should have least upper bounds but don't.

Note that different constructions will give real numbers that look different. However, this is mostly irrelevant, as we rarely care about what real numbers *are*, we care about how they *behave* (the same goes for a *lot* of other mathematical structures as well). Basically the only reason to have a concrete construction (like the cuts) is to demonstrate that a set of numbers with the properties we would like the real numbers to have, actually exists.

Once we have shown that a construction, like the cuts, gives us a set of numbers that have the properties of what we call "real numbers", we forget all about what real numbers are, and change our focus to what properties they have, like an order, least upper bounds, a notion of addition and multiplication, and so on.

Comment: @Arthur..thanks..it took me some time to understand all the replys.. that's why little late reply...two things still are not clear to me...can you please explain them..(1)In second paragraph (where you define cut at start which is same as author Rudin), in second line you said "This is defined to be real number that intuitively corresponds to lub of X." Now here is my first doubt. X is any cut say collection of rationals p such that $p^2 < 2$. Then this set don't have lub in $Q$. Then which lub you are saying here? (second doubt I am writing below)

Comment: In theorem 1.20 part (a), author gave archimedian property. He says " If $x \in R, y \in R, x > 0$, then there is a positive integer n such that $nx > y$. Here I am not getting how the term $"nx"$ is making sense. n is clearly some "positive integer" but $x$ is real number which can be anything depending on our structure of real field, like according to author's construction of real field, $x$ is cut which is certain subset of $Q$, then how is the operation "nx" is defined?

Comment: @Believer: that is *defined* in the proof using cuts.

Comment: @Believer The operation of adding two reals together (which gives rise to "multiplication by natural number" by way of repeated addition) is a part of the concrete construction of the reals, no matter what construction you use. You need to have such an operation on your concrete construction before it can deserve the name "real numbers", after all. The sum $X+Y$ of two cuts $X, Y$ is defined as the cut consisting of all possible rational numbers $x+y$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.

Comment: @Believer And my second paragraph does gloss over things. What I meant was that, for instance, the cut consisting of all rationals whose square is less than $2$, as well as all negative rationals (don't forget those) _is_ the real number $\sqrt2$, just as we intuitively expect the lub of that cut to be.

Answer (score 2):

> What is a “(real) number”?

The answer to that question isn’t really matter. 
I mean, it doesn’t matter if you describe the real number as something on a “real line” or subsets of $\mathbb Q$. What do we need to know, however, is that how the numbers are related, i.e. what are the sums and products of numbers, can they be compared, etc.

The axiomatic approach to describe the real numbers as a complete ordered field answers such questions. That chapter in Rudin’s book simply tells us that such complete ordered field exists in the set theory background, so the axioms of real numbers has a model in ZFC.

Comment: It *does* matter that there exists a field satisfying the properties we want. So a construction eg by cuts is needed; no amount of chatter about the "normal real field"  conjures it into existence.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I agree with you.